how can I fix the automatic fontsize adjustment in python
I have to create many plots of differnt lengths but constant width. I want a constant fontsize pattern for my titles, axes, etc.
SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIGGER_SIZE = 12
plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title

But when I create the plots with figsize=(10,6.5) or figsize=(10,3.8) it automatically scales the fontsize to the aspect ratio of width to height and my fonts end up looking much different.
Is there anyway to fix this? It is important to have same fontsizes and same widths and the length has to change.

I tried, and I saw no font sizes difference depending on the figure size, I've compared the sizes in two different, differently sized figures active at the same time and I swear "No font sizes difference". Is it possible that you are comparing the font sizes RELATIVE to other figure elements and not comparing the sizes in two different figures at the same time? –

I think the problem came when I save the plots. But I have that fixed now except for one plot where I set ax.axis('equal') - that one still has the wrong fonts. But I have a feeling that can't be fixed

If you dont add a reproducible example, for sure the problem cannot be fixed here on SO

You can use a similar approach to this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 10
BIGGER_SIZE = 12

plt.rc('font', size=SMALL_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)     # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title

# Example function to create plots
def plot(figsize):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    
    ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label='Test Plot')
    
    ax.set_title('Sample Title')
    ax.set_xlabel('X Axis Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis Label')
    ax.legend()
    
    plt.show()


plot((10, 6.5))
plot((10, 3.8))

EDIT:
These are the figures I got:



I'm not quite sure why it works like this but not with my previous approach which to me looks the same, but gave me greatly varying fontsizes.

@spikelucky If you do not show your "failing" code, we cannot tell you what was wrong

Marton, I've downvoted your answer because of a misunderstanding, if you [edit] it I will be able to retract my downvote.

I edited my answer, so now it shows the results I got. The font size of the various labels seems constant to me for both figures. This was the issue if I understood you correctly. However, I should join the others, until we don't see more of your code, it is hard to find a good solution.

one error I had made is that i changed the size of figures which messed up the fonts for those plots
def set_size(w,h, ax=None):
""" w, h: width, height in inches """
if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
l = ax.figure.subplotpars.left
r = ax.figure.subplotpars.right
t = ax.figure.subplotpars.top
b = ax.figure.subplotpars.bottom
figw = float(w)/(r-l)
figh = float(h)/(t-b)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(figw, figh)

I was just really trying to get plots that all look alike. Including things like having the same axes window size regardless of how long my y-axis ticks are, etc. So to fix that I tried the resizing which in turn messed up my fonts. Really my code is far to long to post here. Im sorry. I would delete the question, but I don£tg want to get banned
